# Angular 7 HTTP Post 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: angular, http

For some reason, When submitting the form data first time it is working fine with `Status Code: 200 OK`. But second submission http post method returns `**500 Internal Server Error**` . When I reload the page same issue continue.

Here my try, expert advise please

**TS service**

```
 sendData(): Observable<Disciplines[]>  {
    return this.http.get<Disciplines[]>(this.configService.apiUrl + "data?gf=off");
  }
```

**TS component**

**Form submission**

```
onSubmit() {

this.requestBody = {
        name: { "en": this.form.value.discipline_en, "de": this.form.value.discipline_de },
        description: { "en": this.form.value.description_en, "de": this.form.value.description_de }
      }
    this.dataService.sendData(this.requestBody)
            .subscribe(data => {                  
              this.notificationService.showNotification("success", "", "Created successfully");

            });
}
```

Comment: Look at your _server logs_. You're probably sending a field in your JSON request that the BE doesn't expect, or trying to access a locked resource, or a hundred other potential problems, but it's impossible for us to tell you how to fix your request without knowing _specifically what_ the BE is complaining about.

Comment: Agree with the others, check the server logs. Also, your `sendData()` method should be doing a `this.http.post...` and should have your request body as a param when saving a new entity to maintain proper http method.

Answer (score 4):

Internal server error is self explanatory. Check the logs in the server. You can see that its already reached the server with 200, while processing the request got an exception 500. Something wrong with your backend service.

Comment: on first time form submission, it is working fine. when attempts second time getting 500 error.

Comment: If you have angular issue you should see a js error in the frontend, its a backend server issue. Please check the logs in your backend server. hint: When you post 2 times you might get an error from the db if you have an unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ntwobike, the issue is on your *Server* code, therefore the Internal **Server** error response.

There are a few reasons why the form submission is working the first time after a reload, maybe the form "inits" itself with a value, on some of the controls, and you are not properly restoring to "default" values after the first submission (This happened to me with dropdowns), then since your backend is not able to get all the information it needs it's throwing the error on some property.

Check the server logs, or if you have access to the server code, put some breakpoints on your service.